# Google Test Adapter in Visual Studio: How to use local build of googletest/googlemock

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest, googlemock

To use googletest/googlemock in Visual Studio, I installed the Test Adapter for googletest. When creating a new Google Test project, the actual implementation (lib) of googletest is included by a NuGet-Package. The packages.config file shows the name of the NuGet-Package.

Unfortunately, in my case, this is a googletest only package, but I need googlemock too. So searched for it in the NuGet package manager and found many different third party packages that include both. But some of them are outdated, and some won't compile (maybe different toolset).

That's why I want to not use any NuGet-Package but my local build of the latest googletest/googlemock version from Github. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the NuGet-Package from the project by using the NuGet package manager.

Then include paths of the googletest install directory to the project: In **VC++ Directories** at **Include Directories** add googletest install dir **\include** and at **Library Directory** add googletest install dir **\lib**. Finally in **Linker** at **Input** add **gtestd.lib** and **gmockd.lib** to **Additional Dependencies**.

In my case I also had to change the C/C++ Code Generation Runtime Library from MDd to MTd.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.